# iTunes 11 doesn't remember to show cloud purchases

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-store

On this particular computer, I use iTunes 11 only with my cloud purchases – I don't have any music stored locally. Very often (but not always), when I launch iTunes, it comes up with an empty library because the preference setting to display cloud purchases is switched to off.

I keep switching the preference back on, yet it keeps disabling itself again in the future. Is there any way to get it to stick?

---

Update: even weirder, sometimes when this happens the checkbox to show or hide cloud purchases (in Preferences > Store) actually disappears. Literally, I go into Preferences and it simply isn't there. If I quit and relaunch multiple times, eventually it comes back and then I can reenable it. I'll take a screenshot the next time this happens.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem so I telephoned Apple support and the first thing they told me to do was to check the same setting on my other devices. I discovered that my iMac had the option in preferences un-checked and it seems that this was over-riding the option on my MacBook Air.

This has worked for me, so I suggest that you check the preferences on any other devices you have and make them all the same. This is probably a bug that Apple need to sort out because if you want the option on one device but not the other then you will cause the conflict.

Comment: That makes sense, but this is the only machine I use (my wife has iTunes 11 on her machine, but it's set up with her Apple ID, not mine). My old PowerBook has iTunes 10 installed and can't be upgraded to 11.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I encountered the same problem so this is for anyone else with this issue.

To correct it, you need to access your iTunes account from within iTunes.

- Go to **iTunes Store > Quick Links > Account**.
- It will ask for your password again.
- Login, then go to **Edit > Preferences > Store**.
- You should now see the option to enable iCloud music.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue of the disappearing button in 11.1.2, by quitting iTunes and re-opening.